# how to define a variable inside a stored procedure query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am newbie to Stored Procedures. how can I define a variable to be used inside a sql query? here is my code but when I run this stored procedure I get this error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'or'.

this is my code:

```
 declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)
    Declare @availabilityStatus nvarchar(MAX)
    BEGIN
            IF @Availability = 1
                set @availabilityStatus = '0 or 1 or 2'
            ELSE
                set @availabilityStatus = '1'
            set @sql = 
                'SELECT Distinct P.ProductId, P.BrandId, P.[' + @OrderIndex + ']  FROM Products P INNER JOIN ProductStores PS ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId ' +
                'Where PS.StoreId = @StoreId and (PS.Status = ' + @availabilityStatus + 'or PS.AvailabilityRank < '
```

this `@Availability` variable is an input that I have defined at the beginning of the stored procedure.

Comment: Hint:  `DECLARE`.

Comment: why are you using `Dynamic SQL` ?

Comment: I have declared the variables and updated the code still same error

Comment: And why are you injecting the values? (Also, you SP goes between the `BEGIN...END`, not some before some in the middle.)

Comment: You need to fix the huge injection issue you have here @geekymano.

Comment: `set @availabilityStatus = '0 or 1 or 2'` You can't set your variable like this.  What are you trying to do? Give us some reasoning on what is going on here so we can help you better.

Comment: @Larnu can you give me more information please?

Comment: For example `'...[' + @OrderIndex +']...'` should be `'...' + QUOTENAME(@OrderIndex) +'...'`.

Comment: @WEI_DBA  I have an input named Availability. if Availability is equal to 1 I want to select the values where ps.status is 0 or 1 or 2. otherwise of Availability is equal to 0 I want to select the values where ps.status is equal to 1

Comment: Declare `@availabilityStatus` as a table, then populate the values with what you need. Then in the `Where` clause, `PS.Status IN (Select status from @availabilityStatus)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IN clause will work nicely here as it will work for both single values and a comma-separated list of values..

```html
CREATE PROC YourProcName (@Availability int) 
AS

declare @sql nvarchar(MAX)
Declare @availabilityStatus nvarchar(MAX)

BEGIN
IF @Availability = 1
   set @availabilityStatus = '0, 1, 2'
ELSE
   set @availabilityStatus = '1'

set @sql = 'SELECT Distinct P.ProductId, P.BrandId, P.[' + @OrderIndex + ']  FROM Products P INNER JOIN ProductStores PS ON P.ProductId = PS.ProductId ' + 'Where PS.StoreId = @StoreId and PS.Status IN (' + @availabilityStatus + ') or PS.AvailabilityRank < ' -- the rest of your @sql code

-- the rest of your code
END
GO
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried to add brackets like `(@Availability = 1)`?